# How to use SVN to build a library

Tags: eclipse, ide

I am trying to follow a tutorial, and I am told to:

1- Get the source code for the Java EMV Reader library from http://code.google.com/p/javaemvreader/ and build it.
2- Drop the resulting jar file in lib/.
3- Import the project in Eclipse and build it.

I right click the java files, and choose run as but don't get an option to run as Java Application. I also can not export the files as a JAR file. I have enclosed an image of what I have

After the first comment, I right clicked on my project, and under Maven, chose the option "configure as Maven" project. ( Thank you so much; this must be one of the fastest resolutions in the world )And I can now run the project. I get the window in my pic2, which I have attached. I don't however know what step 2 of the above instructions means. I don't see a lib/ folder. And the project he is refering to in step 3 is on git. Any ideas on what he means? ![pic2]![1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drUDp.jpg)

Comment: Unless you are having issues to *get* the source code, this has nothing to do with Subversion or source control. also, SVN has nothing to do with building a library.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the flags to more accurately describe my question. Are you saying the question is not appropriate or valid? I am hoping that more experienced programers know what the author meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse projects have a "type" and that controls what tools are available.  You probably created a "Basic Project" which means there are no compilers or other Java tools associated with it.  You would want to create a Java Project in Eclipse.

That project does not seem to have Eclipse .project and .classpath files checked into the repository.  It does look to be a Maven project however.  So you would either want the m2eclipse plugins installed, and check this out as a Maven project, which would handle configuring everything else, or you want to use the Checkout As ... option and use the wizard to create a new Java project to checkout.

These are more Eclipse IDE questions than SVN or Subclipse questions.

Comment: @ Mark: Is it ok to mark the comment as solution if I have another question about the same project? Your answer was right on.